# how do i get rid of this error in javafx application using eclipse?

Tags: java, javafx

I started learning javaFX a few days back and i was making simple hello world! application in eclipse, i already set the library as shown in the tutorials but i am getting this error in eclipse console, i am unable to resolve it please help.

my code was

```
package javafx;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class simple extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception 
    {
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String...args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

this is the error shown in eclipse

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._submitForLaterInvocation(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._submitForLaterInvocation(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.submitForLaterInvocation(WinApplication.java:215)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:101)
```

Comment: Look further to where it says: "Caused by"; what's it say?

Comment: Are you including the JavaFX runtime jar in your build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The javafxrt.jar you added **does not** match the version that your JDK has hence there's a mismatch between your java and native javafx libs.

I would suggest you are not adding a library your own but use e(fx)clipse. See https://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/index.html and http://efxclipse.bestsolution.at/install.html (you get an all-in-one build from there)

Comment: Thanks! I hope it will work, I followed what was being done in some tutorial i found on youtube but turned out that it dint work in my case..

Comment: tomsontom sir, I am getting an error during extraction of this eclipse zip file, it says that the name of the directory in which javafx files are there is more than 255 characters long and can't be extracted, is it a problem related to winrar as i am using winrar for extraction, pls resolve my doubt if u can :)

Comment: Unfortunately this was/is a problem in the released version. Try to extract into e.g. on C:\eclipse to keep the path short enough. 

As an alternative you could use the nightly builds who don't have this problem http://downloads.efxclipse.bestsolution.at/downloads/nightly/sdk/. Unfortunately there the CSS-Editor is broken but we are working on a fix which should be available in the next days.